# Typescript subclass property type inheritance

Tags: typescript, inheritance, subclass

Suppose you have 2 classes.

```ts
type Properties<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: boolean;
};

class Parent<T> {
    property: Properties<T> = {} as Properties<T>;
}

class Child extends Parent<{someKey: boolean}> {
    property = {
        someKey: true,
        somethingElse: "hello",
    };
}
```

Why is the Child property not strictly typed and I'm able to add any other keys?

Most probably a question like this has been answered already, but I couldn't wrap my head around of either I'm doing something wrong, or maybe it's by design in TypeScript. My apologies if it's a stupid question.

If I'd initialize this in a constructor, it works fine. Same as if I strictly define the type in the Child class. But in my codebase I have plenty of Child classes, in multiple levels and doing one of the previously mentioned things mean a lot of extra unnecessary code.